# How can I turn off the shrine indicator (or make it stop beeping)?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

The shrine indicator (shrine detector? GPShrine?) has both visual and audio cues, so when I'm near a shrine, it beeps constantly. Unfortunately, I occasionally play the game near other humans who are engaged in their own activities, and my wife is *decidedly* unimpressed with this feature.

When I got the shrine indicator, I could have sworn that the dialogue said I could press [Y] to disable it... but pressing Y pulls out my weapon.

**Ideally, I'd like to just make it stop beeping, but stay on for visual cues. But I'll settle for being able to turn it off entirely at times.**

Comment: Of course, low health no longer beeps - they went for something else this time!

Comment: thanks for asking this - Ive been wondering the same because that beeping is *BEEPING* ANNOYING!

Comment: @Seiyria Pretty sure it also does.

Comment: If you have less than 4 health points or 4 health points, you will start beeping indicating that your life is in danger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As said in the comments by Coded Monkey, you can turn it off by pressing the **Y** button while in the **map screen**.

But I don't know of a way for it to stay on while not doing any noise.

Comment: Well you could mute the Switch. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯